# Micronaut: use Flyway to run db migrations on micronaut-postgres-reactive (based on reactive-pg-client)

Tags: postgresql, micronaut

I have been able to successfully instantiate a connection to PostgreSQL using the reactive driver and config as per the micronaut docs.
See: 
https://docs.micronaut.io/snapshot/guide/index.html#postgresSupport

I have been trying to figure out a way to use flyway to run db migrations but in order to instantiate a flyway bean I need a Datasource which doesn't seem to be possible to get using the reactive driver.

Comment: ...and what's your approach to run Flyway anyways? There are multiple ways of doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a datasource bean to instantiate flyway. You can provide it with the url, username, and password instead.

The micronaut configuration can be injected and read to get the configuration values. `io.micronaut.configuration.postgres.reactive.PgPoolConfiguration`

From their docs:

```
    // Create the Flyway instance and point it to the database
    Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure().dataSource("jdbc:h2:file:./target/foobar", "sa", null).load();

    // Start the migration
    flyway.migrate();
```

Comment: Please add an example. It doesn't work for me

    `ApplicationContext ctx = Micronaut.run(Application.class);
    PgPoolConfiguration options = ctx.getBean(PgPoolConfiguration.class);
    Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure().dataSource(options.getUri(), "resk_user", null).load();`


@MichaelS how did you get it to work?

Comment: Do I need to add the Synchronous JDBC driver on the classpath?

Comment: Yeah, flyway works with the JDBC drivers. You will need that JDBC driver.